# Rails need advice on controller practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

I try to follow RESTfull approach in controllers, but sometimes I need action which won't fit into default ones. E.g. I have an index action rendering all articles which is

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
end
```

but what if I also want search them? should I create separate actions for it, or should I bloat existing controller, like:

```
def index
  if params[:search]
    @articles = Article.where(id: params[:search_id])
  else
    @articles = Article.all
  end
end
```

What is the right way?

Comment: you can use the same action, in my view. Because you are just listing articles, based on some condition. So it's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use same action and create a index action only. And search logic goes to Article model.

You should follow [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form)

Comment: And if you want more separation of concerns use ServiceObjects instead of putting the method into the model.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it in index.  If you want to keep it clean and standardise it you could change the controller code thus:

```
def index
   @articles = Article.search(params[:search])
end
```

and then add a class method in Article

```
class << self
  def search(options={})
    if options.blank?
      return self.all
    else
      ..other search logic
    end
  end
end
```

Note that the example you gave for a search doesn't really make sense as it's specifying the id of the article.  If you already know the id then that's not really a search: you might as well just go to the show page for the article.